# migrations on django server 1.9 failing

Tags: django

I deployed my Django 1.9 project to Webfaction using FTP a few months ago. However I wanted to start automating the deployment process and so managed to link my existing deployment on Webfaction to my bitbucket repo.

My local env is still working fine, can makemigrations and migrate without errors. However, it appears a few migrations in the past don't quite exactly match up, and so extra migrations were copied across when I did a git pull on Webfaction. Now I cannot run makemigrations or migrate on Webfaction anymore - I get the error

`CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph: (0016_auto_20161030_1228, 0003_auto_20161030_1638 in locations). To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge`

If I run this command, I see the following prompt:

```
Merging locations
  Branch 0016_auto_20161030_1228
    - Add field added_by to location
    - Change managers on location
    - Add field latlng to location
    - Add field address to location
    - Alter field latitude on location
    - Alter field longitude on location
    - Alter field country on location
  Branch 0003_auto_20161030_1638
    - Add field added_by to location
    - Change managers on location
    - Add field address to location
    - Add field latlng to location
    - Alter field country on location
    - Alter field latitude on location
    - Alter field longitude on location`

Merging will only work if the operations printed above do not conflict
with each other (working on different fields or models)
Do you want to merge these migration branches? [y/N] Please answer yes or no:
```

I tried merging the migrations, but then got an error after trying to migrate that the column already exists.

Migration files on server:

```
0001_initial.py
0001_initial.pyc
0002_auto_20160416_1046.py
0002_auto_20160416_1046.pyc
0002_location_added_by.py
0002_location_added_by.pyc
0003_auto_20160416_1050.py
0003_auto_20160416_1050.pyc
0003_auto_20161030_1638.py
0003_auto_20161030_1638.pyc
0004_remove_location_category.py
0004_remove_location_category.pyc
0005_fun_nightlife_restaurant_shop.py
0005_fun_nightlife_restaurant_shop.pyc
0006_citycoverimage.py
0006_citycoverimage.pyc
0007_auto_20160416_1754.py
0007_auto_20160416_1754.pyc
0008_auto_20160416_1803.py
0008_auto_20160416_1803.pyc
0009_remove_location_reviews.py
0009_remove_location_reviews.pyc
0010_auto_20160422_1920.py
0010_auto_20160422_1920.pyc
0011_locationimage.py
0011_locationimage.pyc
0012_location_added_by.py
0012_location_added_by.pyc
0013_auto_20161029_1857.py
0013_auto_20161029_1857.pyc
0014_location_address.py
0014_location_address.pyc
0015_auto_20161030_1227.py
0015_auto_20161030_1227.pyc
0016_auto_20161030_1228.py
0016_auto_20161030_1228.pyc
__init__.py
__init__.pyc
```

Migration files on local:

```
0001_initial.py
0001_initial.pyc
0002_auto_20160228_1159.pyc
0002_auto_20160416_1046.py
0002_auto_20160416_1046.pyc
0002_location_reviews.pyc
0003_auto_20160416_1050.py
0003_auto_20160416_1050.pyc
0003_location_city.pyc
0004_auto_20160228_1255.pyc
0004_remove_location_category.py
0004_remove_location_category.pyc
0005_auto_20160228_1431.pyc
0005_fun_nightlife_restaurant_shop.py
0005_fun_nightlife_restaurant_shop.pyc
0006_citycoverimage.py
0006_citycoverimage.pyc
0006_location_category.pyc
0007_auto_20160304_2220.pyc
0007_auto_20160416_1754.py
0007_auto_20160416_1754.pyc
0008_auto_20160304_2221.pyc
0008_auto_20160416_1803.py
0008_auto_20160416_1803.pyc
0009_location_country.pyc
0009_remove_location_reviews.py
0009_remove_location_reviews.pyc
0010_auto_20160305_1505.pyc
0010_auto_20160422_1920.py
0010_auto_20160422_1920.pyc
0011_locationimage.py
0011_locationimage.pyc
0011_location_reviews.pyc
0012_location_added_by.py
0012_location_added_by.pyc
0013_auto_20161029_1857.py
0013_auto_20161029_1857.pyc
0014_location_address.py
0014_location_address.pyc
0015_auto_20161030_1227.py
0015_auto_20161030_1227.pyc
0016_auto_20161030_1228.py
0016_auto_20161030_1228.pyc
__init__.py
__init__.pyc
```

Removing all server migration files and doing a git pull so I only had local migration files didn't work.

I've read up on makemigrations --fake but didn't entirely get it and not sure if that will help.

I do know that the local db tables (PostgreSQL) matches the tables in Webfaction (also PostgreSQL).

Would prefer not to drop my Prod. db. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be running makemigrations on the server at all. That's something you do on your dev machine.

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for the reply. I've now realized that this is where it went wrong, as used to run makemigrations on the server. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I solved this. In case anybody runs into the same issues, this is what worked for me

On the server:

1. manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permissions --exclude contenttypes > db.json
2. delete the database completely
3. remake the database with same credentials
4. delete all migration files (except **init**.py)
5. manage.py migrate
6. git reset --hard HEAD
7. manage.py loaddata db.json (takes a while)

Should now be working. Just make sure that your repo is up-to-date before starting.